# Form hiding due to other forms javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web

I have two forms both are different and have various name/id. I have added a hide/show code for one of the form which is working fine. But unfortunately the other form is also being affected by that.

The code follows as::FORM 1/FORM 2/FORM 1 JS/

```
    <?php 
       echo '<button class="add" id="add_'.$index.'"><B>Add Answer</B></button>';
       echo '<form style="display:none;" name="answer_'.$index.'" method="post" action="output.php" onClick="refresh()">'; // I dont think openning form from row to row would be nice!
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="'. $row['id'].'"/>';
       echo '<textarea  type="text" class="addtext" name="addtext" required id="addtext_'.$index.'" placeholder="Please type your answer here.."  ></textarea>';
       echo '<button onClick="addsubmit('.$index.');" type="submit" id="addsubmit_'.$index.'" class="addsubmit"><B>Submit</B></button>';
       echo '</form>';
    ?>

    <div id="frm">
        <form action="enjoin2.php" method="POST">
        <p>
            <label class="username" style="font-family:verdana"><B>Username</B></label>
            <input type="text" class="user" name="user" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="login" value="Login" />
            <input type="submit" class="register" value="Register" />
        </p>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
           $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.add').click(function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().find('form').slideDown('slow');
                $(this).parent().find('form textarea.addtext').focus();
                $(this).hide();
            });

            $('form').click(function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

            $(window).click(function(e) {
                console.log( $(e.target) );
                if( !$(e.target).is('form') ){
                $('.add').show();
                $('form').slideUp();
              } 

            });
        });
   </script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the form and the add button in the same parent - at the moment your line:

```
$(this).parent().find('form')
```

Is finding both forms as they a both within the parent of the add button

If you change your php to the following, it should fix your error

```html
<?php 
   echo '<div class="wrapper">';
   echo '<button class="add" id="add_'.$index.'"><B>Add Answer</B></button>';
   echo '<form style="display:none;" name="answer_'.$index.'" method="post" action="output.php" onClick="refresh()">'; // I dont think openning form from row to row would be nice!
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="'. $row['id'].'"/>';
   echo '<textarea  type="text" class="addtext" name="addtext" required id="addtext_'.$index.'" placeholder="Please type your answer here.."  ></textarea>';
   echo '<button onClick="addsubmit('.$index.');" type="submit" id="addsubmit_'.$index.'" class="addsubmit"><B>Submit</B></button>';
   echo '</form>';
   echo '</div>';
?>
```

You may also need to change this bit of jQuery:

```js
$(window).click(function(e) {
  console.log($(e.target));
  if (!$(e.target).is('form')) {
    $('.add').show();
    $('form').slideUp(); // this is targetting all forms - you may need to change it to target specific form
  }
});
```

**Update**

ok update based on your comments - get rid of the window click event above and then change your add click so it toggles the button between an add / remove (using the wrapper div above):

```js
$('.add').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var button = $(this),  // get the current button
      form = $(this).parent().find('form'); // get the appropriate form button
  
  if (form.is(':visible')) {
    // run this code if your form is visible
    form.slideUp();
    button.text('Add Answer'); // change the button text so it says add answer
  } else {
    // run this code if the form is not visible
    form.slideDown('slow');
    form.find('textarea.addtext').focus();
    button.text('Hide answer'); // change the button text so it says hide answer
  }

});
```

Comment: that's because of the second piece of code in my answer above.  How do you know which one you want to hide if you are just clicking on the window and you have three forms, which form is it meant to target?

Comment: Then how can we tell it. Should we call it by name instead of form..?

Comment: You need to think how you want to hide the form - do you want to hide all forms that have been shown when you click the add button?  Or do you want to add a remove button that hides the specific form?

Comment: How can we tell it to hide specific form?

Comment: give the form a class and then target it - eg give the form a class of `class="added-form"` then target it `$('form.added-form').slideUp()`

Comment: will it work if i add 'id' instead of name to the form?

Comment: ID also works (same as class but more specific) Also see my updated answer for showing / hiding form with the button

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be found in this line:

```
$(this).parent().find('form').slideDown('slow');
```

You're looking for ALL forms that are below the button's parent, which is all your forms.

Try moving the button inside the form and use

```
$(this).parents('form').slideDown('slow');
```

or use the following if the form is always the next element

```
$(this).next('form').slideDown('slow');
```